# Scrollview with View loaded from xib

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, xib

I have a problem here. For last 3-4 days I'm trying to the find the solution but no avail. I'm using a xib to load a view as a subview to scrollView.
I'm using iOS8 and size classes and auto-layout as well. 
The problem is that the view gets added to the scrollview but scrollview is unable to go beyond a point. That is I'm not able to scroll till the bottom.
This is frustrating as I have just started to develop iOS apps.

I'm attaching the screenshots for the constraints that I have applied. Hope to get some help here.

[image]

The first screenshot is the actual view controller's view that holds the scrollview.And the Place Detail Info View is the placeholder where the view loaded from xib is added. The screenshot also lists the different constraints as well.

The second and third screenshots is of the xib file which i'm trying to load into scrollView.

[image]

[image]

Please let me know where I have gone wrong.

Comment: If you add a view to scrollView ([scrollView addSubview:view], do you set after them Constraints for view?

Comment: The view gets automatically added to scrollview since I have overridden the init coder in my custom view. Also I have not re-added the constraints for the added view

Comment: Hard to see, but it looks like you have the height of the subview set to 367?  Is that the actual height of the view contained in the xib?  If not, you're truncating the view with that height constraint.  Can you also share the code you're using to load the xib and add it to the storyboard?

Comment: @jeffro37 the height of the view loaded from xib is greater than 367(may 600 I suppose). The code to load the xib is nothing much. I just created a view which holds all the subviews of xib connected through Interface Builder. Sorry for late response.

Comment: @nikhil.thakkar Try setting the height of that subview to 600 and see what happens.  I think your answer might be to set the height constraint based on the actual height of the view in the xib, but testing this is the first step.

Comment: I have tried that as well but it doesn't seem to work for me. I'm seriously missing something here.

Comment: tell me one thing about the view that is inside your scrollview,i think its height*width is 600*600...right

Comment: Yes.. I'm using size classes

Answer (score 1):

As said above, the issue is related with the content size of your scroll view. Just try adding width and height (*either explicit or implicit: see explanation below*) constraints to **every** direct subview of your scroll view and then define all distance constraints among those.
* By "implicit" width/height constraints I mean things like "aspect ratio", "equal width/height" relation between two views. 
P.S. When dealing with scroll view-like controls and auto layout, there should be an exhaustive (some of which may seem redundant) set of constraints for subviews.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I have added all the relevant constraints to all the views in scrollview. But still it doesn't work. I was able to scroll after I manually set the content size to hardcoded value but this approach fails on iPhone 6 and 6 plus.

Comment: As I can't see the whole picture of what you've got, I can only recommend you to set the content size of the scroll view to yourScrollView.bounds.size when viewDidLayoutSubviews is being called (I assume that there're no content insets inside your scroll view and that you use view controllers). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the view who is immediate subview of your scrollview.In autolayout,scrollView calculate its content size according to its subview.

follow these steps after removing all constarints from this view,i hope u will get your problem solved.

1.for your scroll view,set all 4 constraints i.e leading edge,trailing edge,superview and bottom constraints.

2.now for the view that is immediate subview to your scrollview,set all 4 constraints (leading,trailing,top and bottom),along with these set height constraints and make width equals to scrollview.
if your immediate subview's height is greater than your screen size or scrollview,it will scroll for sure.

run and check whether you are able to scroll and proceed furthur.

after step 2,all your constarints related ambgious type error will resoved.now you can set all other constraints as usual.

for more clear understanding setting constarints in scrollview see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oCWxHLBQ-A

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have done exact same stuff that you are suggesting. You can see all the constraints in the screenshots I have shared. The problem is that the view is loaded from xib at run time.

Comment: As u said u overridden the init method,can u show me that method what u done in that

Answer (score -1):

In interface builder itself there is an option to preview your constraints for all the available devices. This will ensure you that the constraints work fine for all the available devices from Apple. Here is a quick tutorial that will help you with it.

http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2014/08/working-with-size-classes-in-interface-builder/

Once that is verified and you are still not able to find a suitable solution, then probably there is something wrong in the content size for your scroll view. Try to increasing your scroll view content size.
I hope this should solve your problem.

Happy coding. Cheers :)

Comment: The preview option is broken as I suppose because when I see the preview the view is already out of the bounds of the screen as I'm using size classes but it runs fine on actual devices. Also I tried changing the content size but it doesn't work.

Comment: I strongly believe that you should fix it in the interface builder and add appropriate constraints to it and then check it in the preview if it works accordingly or not.

Comment: I really don't know what to do here. The layout looks fine in every real device. iOS development is not at par with Android although being an expensive platform.